# Inconspicuous social control

Tags: alternate-worlds, civilization, control

Civilization A has a fixed population; so they need armies from outside sources to protect themselves.  After many years of reign over a nearby civilization (Civilization B) to supply armies for A, several uprisings have cut into the population of A.  A therefore decides to impregnate B with a religion where certain "signs" or "prophecies" would make B act predictably if A forced these signs. Control from A was covertly maintained by this religious impregnation and drugging the city's water supply.

What drug would A use to force chemical dependency on B; so they don't just leave B?

Drug specifications:

- Must be water miscible
- Must induce mild torpor
- Must induce mild euphoria
- Must be effective at low concentrations
- Must maintain effectiveness after repeat exposure

Answers will be evaluated by which drug has the largest effect while going unnoticed by the user.  (e.g. drugs with few side-effects will be favorable to drugs with severe or many side-effects)
Bonus points for drugs which include other qualities to help make users impressionable.

*mind altering parasites are also viable

Comment: This sounds like an idea generation

Comment: Out of context here?

Comment: I like where it's going, but as written you are asking for ideas and those don't work in the SE

Comment: I will update answer in a bit

Comment: If your question gets closed, someone can nominate for reopening it after you complete your edits.

Comment: I still think this is too broad/sounds like idea generation. Also something to consider...how would you define the criteria for an answer to be accepted? I had an idea for a clever answer: **dihydrogen monoxide**. City B would be completely chemically dependent on it, and if there was none of it elsewhere, they couldn't leave. And as you imply, City A already has control of the water supply. But, I doubt this is the type of answer you're looking for.

Comment: Well... Do I really need to explicitly say drug as defined by US FDA?  Which would rule out food/water.  Either way, I will work on it some more.

Comment: What is the point of this takeover effort?  What is city A trying to accomplish by drugging the other population and how is religion relevant to the conversation.  These details will help make the question more clear and concise.

Comment: If you already have religious impregnation, what do you still need the drugs for? People are gullible enough to accept religion even without being drugged.